# PDF of Normal distribution and probability of a point is $0$ in continuous random variable

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, lebesgue-measure

I learned two things in elementary statistics class - the concept of continuous random variable and probability of a point in continuous random variable is $0$ because the area is $0$ over the point (geometric understanding of probability?).

But when we are talking about (standard) normal distribution, it has a functional form of pdf $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}\left(x\right)^2}$ and this value can be "evaluated" at any point, for example, if $x=0$ then $f(0) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}}$ which is not $0$.

So I am confused here, the point of normal distribution looks life definitely get assigned non-zero values of probability.

What kind of confusion do I have at this point?

Comment: The density does not represent a probability. Here you are trying to apply $f(x) = P(X=x)$, which is not true.

Comment: To reinforce Zhang's comment: probability density functions are exactly *that*--densities of probabilities, i.e. probabilities per unit. Therefore, multiplying by the units gives a probability $P(X\in [x, x+dx]) \approx f(x)dx$ or more precisely $P(X\in (a,b))=\int_a^b f(x) dx$. Also, there are nice analogies between the expected value of a random variable $\int x f(x) dx$ and the center of mass of some object. So if you know some physics, it should not be a surprise that $P(X=x)=\int_x^x f(u)du=0$ for a continuous density function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Andrew Zhang's comment, the values of $f$ are *probability densities* not probabilities. In order to get probabilities you need to integrate over some interval, the probability that you select a value in $[a,b]$ is
$$
\int_{a}^bf(x) \, dx,
$$
and if $a=b$, then this is zero.

If you are interested in the probability of selecting a value *close to* $0$ (say in $[-\delta, \delta]$) the appropriate integral is
$$
\int_{-\delta}^\delta f(x) \, dx
$$

Practically, you could use the PDF to estimate the probability that $X \in [x-\delta, x+\delta]$, we know it is approximately equal to $2\delta f(x)$ (for small enough $\delta$), i.e. that the probability of selecting a value in $[-\delta,\delta]$ is roughly $\frac{\sqrt{2} \delta}{\pi}$.